# Writing tui image editor canvass to server

Tags: javascript, php, css, canvas

I am using [Tui Image editor](https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor). Specifically, I am working from example 01 Include UI.

I need to get the edited image from the canvas and write it back to the server. How do I solve this problem?

I found what I have tried below changed to:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("upper-canvas ");
```

with the trailing space after canvas as I see it when inspecting.

#### html

```
<div>
    <button onClick="saveCards();">Save</button>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveCards()
{ 
  var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("upper-canvas ");
  var i;
  alert("stops");
  var theString = canvas.toDataURL();

  var postData = "CanvasData="+theString;
  var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("POST", 'saveCards.php', true);
  ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'canvas/upload');

  ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(ajax.readyState == 4) {
      alert("image was saved");
    } else {
      alert("image was not saved");
    }
  }
  ajax.send(postData);
}
</script>
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']));
{

$rawImage=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
$removeHeaders=substr($rawImage,strpos($rawImage, ",")+1);
  $decode=base64_decode($removeHeaders);
  $fopen= fopen('image/image.png', 'wb');
  fwrite($fopen, $decode);
  fclose($fopen);
}
?>
```

I get the "stop" error which I would assume means it is not getting the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

The current lacks of documentation makes it hard to find the information you're looking for.

If someone wondering how to achieve this (as I was), you can use the imageEditor.toDataURL() to get the image data, then convert it to BLOB. This can then be sent via ajax (I'm using jQuery but this could be done using plain javascript).

The server (APACHE + PHP in my instance) would then receive $_FILES['croppedImage'] which you can use to store on your server however you want. (There are many tutorial explaining that step)

```js
// LAUNCH TUI EDITOR
var imageEditor = new tui.ImageEditor('#tui-image-editor', {
    includeUI: {
        loadImage: {
            path: 'sampleimage.png',
            name: 'SampleImage'
        },
        theme: whiteTheme,
        initMenu: 'filter',
        menuBarPosition: 'left'
    },
    cssMaxWidth: 700,
    cssMaxHeight: 1000,
    usageStatistics: false
});

// MAKE THE EDITOR RESPONSIVE
window.onresize = function() {
    imageEditor.ui.resizeEditor();
}

// FUNCTION TO CONVERT DATA-URL to BLOB
function dataURLtoBlob(dataurl) {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
}

// JQUERY 
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    // LISTEN TO THE CLICK AND SEND VIA AJAX TO THE SERVER
    $('.doSaveFile').on('click', function (e) {

        // GET TUI IMAGE AS A BLOB
        var blob = dataURLtoBlob(imageEditor.toDataURL());

        // PREPARE FORM DATA TO SEND VIA POST
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('croppedImage', blob, 'sampleimage.png');

        // SEND TO SERVER
        $.ajax({
            url: '/files/upload_files/', // upload url
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY, PLEASE TRY AGAIN...');
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert('UPLOAD FAILED, PLEASE TRY AGAIN...');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using react, you can use this method.

use imageEditor.toDataURL() to get the image data. then convert it to BLOB. and then convert it to JPEG. I'm using API to sent an image to the server.

canvas image editor

```
<ImageEditor
                                ref={editorRef}
                                includeUI={{
                                  loadImage: {
                                    path:
                                      APP_URL + imageName,
                                    name: imageName,
                                  },
                                  theme: myTheme,
                                  menu: [
                                    "filter",
                                    "crop",
                                    "flip",
                                    "rotate",
                                    "text",
                                  ],
                                  initMenu: "filter",
                                  menuBarPosition: "bottom",
                                }}
                              />
```

save function and sent it to server.

```
saveImage(image) {
const editorInstance = editorRef.current.getInstance();
const data = editorInstance.toDataURL();
var blob = dataURItoBlob(data);
const file = new File([blob], `edited-` + image, {
  type: "image/jpeg",
  lastModified: new Date(),
});

DataService.upload(file, (event) => {})
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      let nextMessage = [...prev.message, "File successfully Sent"];
      return {
        message: nextMessage,
      };
    });
    return DataService.getFiles();
  })
  .then((files) => {
    this.setState({
      fileInfos: files.data,
    });
  })
  .catch(() => {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      let nextMessage = [...prev.message, "Could not sent the file"];
      return {
        message: nextMessage,
      };
    });
  });}
```

function convert dataurl to blob.

```
dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
var mimeString = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];

var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
  ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}

return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });}
```